# Solution Explorer in Visual Studio weird signs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, solution-explorer

I randomly clicked some key combinations (by mistake) and my Solution Explorer has these weird signs next to the things there. Lock signs and red dots:

[image]

What are these for?  Can I get rid of them?

Comment: you added your project to source control. Those icons show you if you have pending changes for instance. In stead of getting rid of them you should take a look at source control, it's a good thing to have on your projects.

Comment: Well, at least now i know what these things are but still I am not really sure if i need them :/ And as i mentioned they reeeeeeeeally annoy the hell out of me :D

Comment: There's a menu for source control under the File menu, check there and you should find an option to remove it. Just so you know, source control is like this cool backup that allows you to roll back in time to any version of your project. So if you really mess something up, just get one of your earlier versions and continue from there :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the info :)